# How to access object within a JSON object in Angular 2+?

Tags: javascript, json

I am a beginner in Angular. I tried to access this JSON object using `console.log(this.selected[0].delivery.shipping_type);`. `selected` is an array and I am trying to show the 0<sup>th</sup> element of selected. How to access `shipping_type` within `delivery`. `console.log()` returns this error:

> Cannot read property 'shipping_type' of undefined.`

```
selected[0] = {
    createdAt: "2019-09-20T01:47:27.291Z"
    delivery.address: "21 Woodlands Crossing, Singapore 738203"
    delivery.contact_no: "738203"
    delivery.postal_code: "738203"
    delivery.recepient: "Dhania"
    delivery.shipping_fee: 5
    delivery.shipping_type: "regular"
    delivery.unit_no: "#03-07",
    __v: 0
    _id: "5d842faf06f2a639183226c0"
}
```

Comment: Could you create a demo of your problem in https://stackblitz.com/ so we can investigate further?

Comment: I got the json object from database and tried to console it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot notation will look for an object `delivery` which contains a key `shipping_type`. Your object contains `delivery.shipping_type` as the key.

Access it using `[]` with the key as a string like below.

```js
console.log(this.selected[0]["delivery.shipping_type"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
selected = [{createdAt: "2019-09-20T01:47:27.291Z11",
            address: "21 WoodlandsCrossin11gSingapore 738203",
            contact_no: "73820311",
            postal_code: "73820113",
            recepient: "Dhani11a",
            shipping_fee: 15,
            shipping_type: "r11egular",
            unit_no: "#03-071"}]


selected[0].shipping_type
```

change your key name.